# how can i make my own toggle pause/play button work with my video?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to make my own toggle pause/play button for the longest to no avail. Someone please help me out. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here's the code below:

```js
  const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
  const video = wrapper.querySelector('.dvid');
  const togglePause = wrapper.querySelector('.toggle-pause');
  const toggleSound = wrapper.querySelector('.toggle-sound');


function togglePlay() {
    const isPlaying = video.paused ? play : pause;
    video[isPlaying]();
}


function toggleBtn() {

  if (this.paused) {
      togglePause.innerHTML= '<img src="play.png">';
  }
  else {
      togglePause.innerHTML= '<img src="pause.png">';
  }
}

function toggleS() {

}

video.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
video.addEventListener('pause', toggleBtn);
video.addEventListener('play', toggleBtn);
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">

      <video class="dvid" autoplay loop muted>
          <source src="2am freestyle.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
          <p>This browser does not support this video</p>
      </video>


  <footer class="indexfooter">
    <div class="video-controls">
        <button class="toggle-pause">
          <img src="pause.png"> 
        </button>
        <button class="toggle-sound">
          <img onClick src="mute.png"> 
        </button>

    </div>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've also tried this as well

function togglePlay() {

     if (video.paused === true) {

       video.play();

       togglePause.innerHTML= '<img src="play.png">';

     }
     else {

        video.pause();

        togglePause.innerHTML= '<img src="pause.png">';

    }

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this function, You added value as variable instead of string. If you open devtools there will be error stating `Uncaught ReferenceError: pause is not defined`

```
function togglePlay() {
    const isPlaying = video.paused ? 'play' : 'pause';
    video[isPlaying]();
}
```

**Working example**

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const video = wrapper.querySelector('.dvid');
const togglePause = wrapper.querySelector('.toggle-pause');
const toggleSound = wrapper.querySelector('.toggle-sound');


function togglePlay() {
  const isPlaying = video.paused ? 'play' : 'pause';
  video[isPlaying]();
}


function toggleBtn() {
  if (this.paused) {
    togglePause.innerHTML = '&#9616;&nbsp;&#9612;';
  } else {
    togglePause.innerHTML = '&#9658;';
  }
}

video.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
video.addEventListener('pause', toggleBtn);
video.addEventListener('play', toggleBtn);

togglePause.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <video class="dvid" autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <p>This browser does not support this video</p>
  </video>


  <footer class="indexfooter">
    <div class="video-controls">
      <button class="toggle-pause">&#9658;</button>
      <button class="toggle-sound">Toggle Sound</button>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

**Updated**

Call the same function when button is clicked

```
togglePause.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
```

Comment: thank you! i see what you're saying, but with this example the video only pauses when you click the video and that is what toggles the play/pause button. How can I command the button itself to play and pause the video?

Comment: thanks again. i upvoted. it said votes caused by ppl with less than 15 reputation points are recorded but not shown publicly. One more thing though. I copy and pasted your code into visual studio code to see if it would work before incorporating it into mine, but it didn't. However it worked perfectly on codepen. When I inspect elements on live server of visual studio code it says, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" for each of my event listeners.  Do you know why this is?

Comment: Actually never mind!! I just moved my <script></script> to the last line in my index and everything works now! thanks for the assistance my guy